# complex analysis -bounded but not holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

What are some examples of functions that are bounded but not holomorphic?

I know that some the not holomorphic functions are

Absolute value function, Piecewise functions (not analytic where the pieces meet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can take any bounded discontinuous function. For example,

$f(z) = 1$ if $z = 0$ and $f(z) = 0$ otherwise is bounded and discontinuous and hence not holomorphic.

Comment: thanks vishal, is there any other possible answers too.

Comment: you may probably know Liouville's theorem. A bounded entire function is constant. So in a sense, a holomorphic function is never bounded unless it is a constant.

Comment: think about the familiar sine and cosine function. They are bounded on the real domain. On the complex domain, they are not...although this is not what you have asked for. But I just want to highlight the difference between the real and complex situations.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it is the case that *almost all* bounded functions are nonholomorphic, by which I mean that if you pick a random bounded function on some domain $D$, there is a $0\%$ chance it will be holomorphic.  Intuitively, one can simply assign all the elements of $D$ to arbitrary meaningless values (as long as the values are bounded) and the result will be discontinuous, and thus nonholomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the absolute value function and *make* it bounded, like for example $$
  f(z) = \frac{|z|}{1+|z|} \leq 1 \text{.}
$$

You get (assuming that $z=u+iv$ and using that $|z|=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$) $$\begin{aligned}
  \frac{\partial \Re f}{\partial u} &= \frac{-u|z|^{-1}(1+|z|) + u}{(1+|z|)^2} = -\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\left(1+\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\right)^2} \\
  \neq\frac{\partial \Im f}{\partial v} &= 0 \text{.}
\end{aligned}
$$
i.e. $f$ is not holomorphic.